# Breezejs flips the EntityState from Added to Modified before Save

Tags: breeze

I am building a SPA per the guidance provided in John Papa's Jumpstart.
When I create the model, it has

modelObservable().entityAspect.entityState.isAdded() = true;

I update the text, dropdown and 
modelObservable().entityAspect.entityState.isAdded() = false;

in my Datacontext:

```
  var createProject = function (position) {
            return manager.createEntity(entityNames.project,
                {
                    positionId : position.id(),
                    start : position.start(),
                    memberId : position.memberId()
                });
        };
```

which is called from my add viewModel:

```
   define(['services/datacontext', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'services/logger', 'services/uiService'],
    function (datacontext, router, system, app, logger, ui) {
        var model = ko.observable();
        var position = ko.observable();
        var hourTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
        var isSaving = ko.observable(false);
        // init
        var activate = function (routeData) {
            logger.log('Add View Activated', null, 'add', true);
            var positionId = parseInt(routeData.id);

            initLookups();
            return datacontext.getPositionById(positionId, position).then(**createProject**);
        };

        var initLookups = function () {
            logger.log('initLookups', null, 'add', true);
            hourTypes(datacontext.lookups.hourTypes);
        };

        // state

        **var createProject = function () {
            return model(datacontext.createProject(position()));
        }**

        var addNewProject = function () {
            if (position == undefined || position().id() < 1) {
                console.log('callback addNewProject');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    addNewProject();
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                datacontext.addProject(position(), model);
                console.log(model().id());
                return;
            }
        }

        var **save** = function () {
            isSaving(true);
            **datacontext.saveChanges()**
                    .then(goToEditView).fin(complete);

            function complete() {
                isSaving(false);
            }
            function goToEditView() {
                isSaving(false);
                var url = '#/Projects/';
                router.navigateTo(url + model().id());
            }
        };

        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            hourTypes: hourTypes,
            isAdded: isAdded,
            model: model,
            save: save,
            title: 'Details View'
        };

        return vm;

});
```

the html

```
<section  data-bind="with:model">
     <h1 data-bind="text: name"> <i class="icon-asterisk" data-bind="visible: hasChanges" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></h1>
        <div class="errorPanel"></div>
        <div id="overview" class="project" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                    <label class="requiredLabel">Name*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" data-bind="value: name" style="width: 27em;" class="required" placeholder="Project Name" required validationMessage="Project Name required" /><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="title"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3"><label class="requiredLabel">Start*</label></div>
                <div class="span3"><label class="requiredLabel">End</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3"><input name="start" data-bind="shortDate: start" class="date required" required="required" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" style=" width:142px"></div>
                <div class="span3"><input name="end"   data-bind="shortDate: end"  class="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"  style=" width:142px"><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="end"></span></div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3"><label for="hourType" class="requiredLabel">Measure As*</label></div>
                <div class="span2"><label for="hoursPerWeek" class="requiredLabel">Hours/Week</label></div>
                <div class="span2"><label for="totalHours" class="requiredLabel">Total Hours</label></div>
            </div>   
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <select id="hourType" data-bind="options: $parent.hourTypes, optionsText: 'name', value: hourType" required validationMessage="Measure As required"></select><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="hourType"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <input name="hoursPerWeek" type="number" min="1" max="120" required="required" data-bind="value: hoursPerWeek,  validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }, enable: hourType().id() == 1" class="hours required"" style="width: 80px;"  validationMessage="Hours required"><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="projectHours"></span>
                    <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="totalHours"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <input name="totalHours" type="number"  min="40" max="2080" required="required" data-bind="value: totalHours,  validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }, enable: hourType().id() == 2" class="hours required"" style="width: 80px;"  validationMessage="Hours required"><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="projectHours"></span>
                    <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="totalHours"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                    <label class="requiredLabel">Description*</label><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="description"></span><span id="posMinDesc" style="visibility:hidden"></span>
                    <textarea id="description" name="description" style="height: 200px; width: 650px;" data-bind="value: description, enabled:true, click: $parent.clearDefaults" rows="4" cols="60" class="richTextEditor k-textbox" required validationMessage="Description required" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    <div class="button-bar">
        <button class="btn btn-info"  data-bind="click:  $parent.goBack"><i class="icon-hand-left"></i> Back</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info"  data-bind="click:  $parent.save, enable:  $parent.canSave"><i class="icon-save"></i> Save</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

The json breeze sends to my controller is this:

{
  "entities": [
    {
      **"Id": -1,**
      "Description": "poi",
      "End": null,
      "Gauge": 0,
      "Score": 0,
      "HourTypeId": 1,
      "HoursPerWeek": 45,
      "HourlyRate": null,
      "TotalHours": null,
      "WeightedHours": 0,
      "CreditMinutes": 0,
      "TotalCompensation": null,
      "IsCurrent": false,
      "Name": "poi",
      "PositionId": 1,
      "MemberId": 1,
      "Start": "2011-09-01T00:00:00Z",
      "undefined": false,
      "entityAspect": {
        "entityTypeName": "Project:#SkillTraxx.Model",
        "defaultResourceName": "Projects",
        "entityState": "**Modified**",
        "originalValuesMap": {
          "Name": "",
          "HourTypeId": 0,
          "HoursPerWeek": null,
          "Description": ""
        },
        "autoGeneratedKey": {
          "propertyName": "Id",
          "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "saveOptions": {}
}

As you can see, the above is incorrect b/c state is "Modified" and the Id = -1. This throws an error server side. I suppose I could trap the DbUpdateConcurrencyException,  unwind the JObject and change "Modified" to added, but that's got code smell all over it.

If anyone can help me find the face-palm moment in all of this, I'm ready.
Thanks for looking!

Comment: Can you try modelObservable.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded() ?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, but unfortunately that wouldn't work. That is a read only value. model().entityAspect.entityState.isAdded(true); or model().entityAspect.entityState.isAdded() = true;

Comment: We can't tell where you are calling is added, what code is run before you call it, or anything else from your example.  We can't tell where you are calling the entityState check, but if you are doing something where you already have the value of the observable (such as in a arrayForEach loop or something) you don't need the () but that *probably* isn't the case as it should throw an error, just stabbing at a possibility.  Can you post the code where you are testing entityState?

Comment: observing the state in the browser. It is in 'Add' state when the html renders to the screen, but when I hit the save, it is in Modified state, so the post to the server is doomed. I just can't for the life of me know why it's changing from Add to Edit under the covers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity you have no computed of canSave, is that just something you didn't copy over?  Also when you are performing the save and then call goToEditView you are setting save to false, and again when finishing the call, just FYI.  Gonna keep looking just a couple of standouts

Comment: Also your var (functionName) = function () {  } calls are missing the ; at the end, are you sure they aren't saving in IE or something where it recognizes a missing ;?

Comment: Last comment : ) Can you paste your code into a fiddle so we can edit it together I see a few mistakes that can't be helping it, don't know they are the root cause but easy starts.

Comment: Better yet maybe simplify the example and create a very simple test case that illustrates the issue. We've been unable to repro this.

Comment: Gents, thank you, for your advice and support. Jay, and thank you for building/sharing breeze. I've had a few 'cry-in-my-lunchbox' moments along the learning curve, but progress is being made. I do have some server side processing that certain saves need to make that are far different than plain CRUD. Is there any guidance on how to handle entity specific saves where they're managed differently server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FACE PALMED IT
I took Jays advice and started stripping away the html then I realize it was my handler.
The update method on shortDate handler was responsible. I wrapped it in an if statement not to send the update if the current state is added.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.shortDate = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        //attach an event handler to our dom element to handle user input
        element.onchange = function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();//get our observable
            //set our observable to the parsed date from the input
            value(moment(element.value).toDate());
        };
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
        if (valueUnwrapped) {
            element.value = moment(valueUnwrapped).format('L');
            if (!viewModel.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded())
            {
                **viewModel.entityAspect.setModified();**
            }
        }
    }
};
```